# Working page counter in tikz image in repeating fancyhdr?

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-numbering, fancyhdr, pageref, setcounter

I'm trying to generate a aggregated document, that consists of several sub-sequent documents with similar footers and headers:

```
┌────────────────┐
│fixed header    │
├────────────────┤
│some content    │
├────────────────┤
│    page 1 of 3 │
└────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│fixed header    │
├────────────────┤
│other content   │
├────────────────┤
│    page 2 of 3 │
└────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│fixed header    │
├────────────────┤
│more content    │
├────────────────┤
│    page 3 of 3 │
└────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│                │
│empty page using│
│\cleardoublepage│
│                │
└────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│fixed header    │
├────────────────┤
│some content    │
├────────────────┤
│    page 1 of 2 │
└────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│fixed header    │
├────────────────┤
│other content   │
├────────────────┤
│    page 2 of 2 │
└────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│                │
│empty page using│
│\cleardoublepage│
│                │
└────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│fixed header    │
├────────────────┤
│some content    │
├────────────────┤
│    page 1 of 3 │
└────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│fixed header    │
├────────────────┤
│other content   │
├────────────────┤
│    page 2 of 3 │
└────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│fixed header    │
├────────────────┤
│more content    │
├────────────────┤
│    page 3 of 3 │
└────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│fixed header    │
├────────────────┤
│another page!   │
├────────────────┤
│    page 4 of 4 │
└────────────────┘
```

My problem: the footer is basically a *tikzpicture* within an `\fancyfoot` environment. Which in turn contains the page numbering, using `\pageref{lastpage}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,notitlepage,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[top=32mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,bottom=95pt,twoside=false]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\fancyhf{}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhead[R]{
        \bf header text
    }
    \fancyfoot[C]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,xscale=-1]
          \draw[black] (0,0) -- (160mm,0mm);
          \node[anchor=south east] at (0,0) {page \thepage\ of \pageref{lastpage}};
          \node[anchor=north east] at (128mm,-3mm){\includegraphics[width=65mm]{letter_footer}};
          % more drawing omitted
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

some content

\newpage

other content

\newpage

more content
\label{lastpage}
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}

some content

\newpage

other content

\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}

some content

\newpage

other content

\newpage

more content

\newpage 

another page!

\end{document}
```

For the first three pages, the numbering is fine, but for subsequent pages, I would need to refer to another label. And I don`t know how to do this without redefining the whole pagestyle.

Comment: use a counter that you increase with every document, e.g. content (or use e.g. the part counter),  and then set `\label{lastpage\thecounter}` and use `\pageref{lastpage\thecontent}`

Comment: This was my first idea, but somehow I was not able to make it work.

Comment: Darn. I have no idea what went wrong on my fist try, but now I got it right. Will post an answer in a few min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a counter to mark up the parts, e.g. use the part counter if you don't need it:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,notitlepage,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[top=32mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,bottom=95pt,twoside=false]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\fancyhf{}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhead[R]{
        \bf header text
    }
    \fancyfoot[C]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,xscale=-1]
          \draw[black] (0,0) -- (160mm,0mm);
          \node[anchor=south east] at (0,0) {page \thepage\ of \pageref{lastpage\thepart}};
          %\node[anchor=north east] at (128mm,-3mm){\includegraphics[width=65mm]{letter_footer}};
          % more drawing omitted
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

some content

\newpage

other content

\newpage

more content
\label{lastpage\thepart}
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}\stepcounter{part}

some content

\newpage

other content
\label{lastpage\thepart}

\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}\stepcounter{part}

some content

\newpage

other content

\newpage

more content

\newpage

another page!
\label{lastpage\thepart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was about to post this very same answer, too, but with a newly-created counter. Your solution is even better! thx

Comment: ```\label{lastpage\thepart}
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}\stepcounter{part}
```
may in turn be defined as new command, which makes it even easier!

Comment: Why do you use the option `twoside` of the `article` documentclass and `twoside=false` in the `geometry` package? And why do you mix the units `mm` and `pt` (`geometry` package options)?

Comment: @Unknown because I simply copied the example from the question and didn't clean up.